# Working with Bitmaps in WxWidgets

Tags: c++, windows, bitmap, wxwidgets

I have the following code given in the book "*Cross-Platform GUI Programming with wxWidgets*" which I'm reading:

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyWindow, wxWindow)
  EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND(MyWindow::OnErase)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

void MyWindow::OnErase(wxEraseEvent& event)
{
    wxClientDC* clientDC = NULL;
    if (!event.GetDC())
        clientDC = new wxClientDC(this);

    wxDC* dc = clientDC ? clientDC : event.GetDC() ;

    wxSize sz = GetClientSize();
    wxEffects effects;
    effects.TileBitmap(wxRect(0, 0, sz.x, sz.y), *dc, m_bitmap);

    if (clientDC)
        delete clientDC;
}
```

This code doesn't show how do I load a bitmap so after some searching on google I came up with:

```
wxBitmap m_bitmap;
bool result = m_bitmap.LoadFile("D:\image.png", wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
```

But this returns a boolean result of `false` which means the function `LoadFile` was failed to load the file. I have also tried to load a BMP file which fails too.

One another problem I'm having is that `wxEffects` is flagged deprecated by the complier warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the PNG image handler to be able to load PNG bitmaps. The simplest way to do is to call [wxInitAllImageHandlers()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__appinitterm.html#ga27f6c78d5d13374a28022b7bd44c6823) function at some point during your application initialization, e.g. in your overridden `MyApp::OnInit()`.

As for `wxEffects` being deprecated, this is just because the book is rather old and quite a few things have changed since then. I strongly recommend you to read the [overview of important changes](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_changes_since28.html) if you are using wxWidgets 3.0. And if you don't, I recommend you even stronger to use it.

Comment: Can you comment on why `MyApp::OnInit()` is an override function? E.g. Even If I remove the `virtual` then the program still appears to work perfectly fine.

Comment: This is C++, `virtual` is optional. I do recommend using C++11 `override` if you can.